# Meaning of "recommend with reservation"

Tags: recommendation-letter, writing-style

In my reference my tutor has put down that he recommends me with reservation.
Is that a good thing? What does "recommend with reservation" mean?

Thanks everyone for your help.
I spoke to my referee and he realized he had made a typo. I have contacted the universities and told them. They have given me an email address for my referee to submit his reference again which I have passed on. 
The rest of the reference letter was amazing and I am sure that the admission tutor would have picked it up as a typo and would have rung up my referee.

Comment: That sounds like a horrible thing to say in a letter of reference.

Comment: This is absolutely not a good thing; reservation means that the tutor has reservations about your qualifications, but sees potential. Therefore, he recommends you under the assumption that you *can* be qualified for a position, but asserts that you are *not yet* qualified.

Comment: "reservations" means "concerns"

Comment: *with* versus *without* - close enough?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, it's not a good thing. With reservation means that there is a some reason not to recommend you.

However,  "recommend with reservation" is an odd turn of phrase. I suspect it is a typographical error and should read  "recommend without reservation" - which is a good thing. If this is a typo, it is a seriously unfortunate one and you should definitely ask your recommender about this (particularly if you don't know what his reservation could be).

Comment: How do I approach him about this?

Comment: Aha that is a more tricky question. I guess it would depend on the relationship you have with this person. Especially if the rest of the letter is positive (which I am assuming it is), you could say "Thank you for the writing this letter for me. I see you "recommend me with reservation" on line X. I am wondering if this is perhaps a typographical error, and if it is not, would you be willing to elaborate on your reservation?" If the letter is not generally positive, you should bin it and find someone else as this will tank your application.

Comment: The rest of the letter is good expect for the reservation bit

Comment: @user99865 then I am willing to bet it is a typographical error. It sounds like the type word omission mistake I would make. Because "recommend without reservation"  is such a common phrase, I read the title of your post  wrong the first time I saw it.

Comment: He has already submitted my reference to other universities and I bet he has made the mistake for f**k sake. I may need to ring up the universities

Comment: I think if the whole letter is positive, the readers of other universities probably would also guess that's a typo and they may contact your tutor directly for clarification. But normally blind reference is much preferable, so if you have read the reference letter, that seems the university you are applying to do not consider the reference super important...

Comment: I have certainly heard the phrase "recommend with reservation**s**" used, so in my opinion this is quite an unfortunate and dangerous typo.  If every single other bit of the letter is positive a logical reader will have to suspect it's a typo *or* that the writer is not so reasonable....but this would be well worth arranging to get fixed if possible.  (It's also not worth stressing out about: this is obviously not your fault.  See if it can be fixed, but don't lose sleep over it.)

Comment: By the way, the phenomenon of someone who should know infinitely better putting a stupid typo into a highly important (to the recomendee) letter: so much more common than you might think.

Comment: One way to approach the letter writer would be to ask what is meant. If "with" was intended, the student needs to know the nature of the reservation to see if it is fixable. If it is a typo, asking the nature of the reservation would caller the writer's attention to it.

Comment: It was so so lucky I found that typo. Should I also phone the university up and tell them to destroy the previous reference letter?

Comment: The only place I've seen "recommend with reservation" in connection with recommendations is not in the letter but in the list of options on a recommendation form, where the recommender is supposed to check a position on a scale from "strongly recommended" to "not recommended".  Here "recommended with reservations" would be the next-to-last item in the list. If, when reading a recommendation, I saw this option checked, I'd ordinarily look in the letter for an explanation of the reservation; if there isn't one, I'd probably assume it's a typo.